# Self contained publication of .net core 2 console app not deploying correct version of System.Data.SqlClient

Tags: .net-core

I have a little console application I have created using .Net Core 2.0, and on my development machine, whether invoked via Visual Studio 2017 or from the command prompt using the "dotnet" command, everything works fine.

However, when I publish (using dotnet publish) the application as a self contained and then place that on one of our servers, trying to run it gives me an error:

```
Error:
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (Reporter.deps.
json) was not found:
    package: 'System.Data.SqlClient', version: '4.4.0'
    path: 'runtimes/win/lib/netstandard2.0/System.Data.SqlClient.dll'
```

Checking the publish folder, it would seem that the System.Data.SqlClient.dll assembly in there has a version of 4.6.25519.03.

Anyone care to hazard a guess as to why it has published a version other than that which it depends upon?

Martin

Comment: I had a very similar issue with one of my applications which I had upgraded from .NET Core 1.x to 2.0 (when the first preview of .NET Core 2.0 came out). It turned out that one of the old DLLs was still present in the directory that I had uploaded my application to. It happened to me because I hadn't deleted the old deployment when I published from AppVeyor, maybe this is similar.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - certainly something for other people to consider, but this was publishing into a virgin directory...
I'll try again though - worth a punt.

Comment: Ah, sorry that it wasn't as relevant to you.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out @MartinMilan?

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem with my console application written on dotnet 3.1.101. But then I've noticed that forget to copy folder called "runtimes" in my release.